# Previous values in ajax file coming in second request

Tags: php, ajax

For categorizing products on the basis of their category, I'm doing that job through ajax request. Now what happens is When I make a second ajax request (by checking second check box), it takes previously passing values first.

Let's say I've category ids as '11', '12', '13'. On first request I'm passing value '12' to ajax file, on second request, I'm passing value '11' & '12' to the ajax file. What file understands is two requests: One is '12' & the other is '11' & '12'. So it gives wrong results.

Have a look at my code:

**index.php**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_showsubdiv.php",
    data: {cat_id:cat_id,sub_cat:sub_cat,sub_cat1:sub_cat1,sub_cat2:sub_cat2},
    success: function(option){
        $('.autoload').replaceWith(option);
    }
    });
    e.preventDefault;
});
```

**ajax_subdiv.php**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var cat_id= <?php echo $cat_id; ?>;
var sub_cat= <?php echo $sub_cat; ?>;
var sub_cat1= <?php echo $sub_cat1; ?>;
var sub_cat2= <?php echo $sub_cat2; ?>;

$('.autoload').load("ajax_autoload.php", {'group_no':track_load,'sub_cat':sub_cat,
  'sub_cat1':sub_cat1,'sub_cat2':sub_cat2},
  function() {track_load++;}); //load first group

$('.animation_image').delay(2000).fadeOut();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(!flag){
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= ($(document).height()-350))
        {
            if(track_load < total_groups && loading==false)
            {
                loading = true;
                $('.animation_image').show();
                alert(sub_cat);//This two gives total 4 results on second request
                alert(sub_cat1);//First from previous request & second from this request

                $.post('ajax_autoload.php',{'group_no':track_load,
                'sub_cat':sub_cat,'sub_cat1':sub_cat1,'sub_cat2':sub_cat2
                }, function(data){

                    $(".autoload").append(data);
                    $('.animation_image').hide();

                    track_load++;
                    loading = false; 

                }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?

                    alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
                    $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image
                    loading = false;

                });

            }
        }
    }
});
```

});

**ajax_autoload** file just takes the result and display it in my format, that file is working fine.
Can anyone help spot the mistake I'm doing? I've been working for this solution for 3-4 days now.

**EDIT**
What basically I need is, create a fresh new request on every ajax call, forget the previous ones.

Comment: Try using ` $(".autoload").html(data);` instead of ` $(".autoload").append(data);`

Comment: Doesn't help, values are coming before that. It's taking previous values first

Comment: In ajax_showsubdiv.php echo the retrieved values using `$_POST["cat_id"];`. Essentially try changing the assignment like the following: `var cat_id= <?php echo $_POST["cat_id"]; ?>;`. Also, in your index.php code the url is pointing to ajax_showsubdiv.php, but in the example you have mentioned the file as ajax_subdiv.php

Comment: Nah, that's not to be done. I've some conditions like $sub_cat=0; if(isset($_POST['sub_cat']>0)){$sub_cat=$_POST['sub_cat']}

Comment: So then it becomes var sub_cat=<?php echo $sub_cat; ?>; So even though the value is 0, that stays okay